# How to turn array of objects in unique array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my initial data:

```
const data = [
   {
      "user":{
         "amount":"1",
         "date":"2020-07-31T18:34:48.635Z",
         "shiftSelected":"10:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "name":"Name",
         "surname":"aaa",         
         "obs":"eee"
      }
   }
]
```

I'm trying to turn an array of objects in unique array. This is my output:

```
const newData = {
  amount: "1",
  date: "2020-07-31T18:34:48.635Z",
  shiftSelected: "10:00",
  name: "Name",
  surname:"aaa",         
  obs:"eee"    
}
```

I can iterate over the array with a map call: `let b = data.map(item => item.user)`, but I need to write more code to join then. I know that it's possible to do it with one unique logic. I tried but without successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to merge the properties of the objects. Note that with this method, later properties will overwrite previous ones.

```js
const data = [
   {
      "user":{
         "amount":"1",
         "date":"2020-07-31T18:34:48.635Z",
         "shiftSelected":"10:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "name":"Name",
         "surname":"aaa",         
         "obs":"eee"
      }
   }
];
const result = data.reduce((acc,{user})=>Object.assign(acc,user), {});
console.log(result);
```

Object spread syntax will also work.

```js
const data = [
   {
      "user":{
         "amount":"1",
         "date":"2020-07-31T18:34:48.635Z",
         "shiftSelected":"10:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "name":"Name",
         "surname":"aaa",         
         "obs":"eee"
      }
   }
];
const result = data.reduce((acc,{user})=>({...acc, ...user}), {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Zkk Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
   {
      "user":{
         "amount":"1",
         "date":"2020-07-31T18:34:48.635Z",
         "shiftSelected":"10:00"
      }
   },
   {
      "user":{
         "name":"Name",
         "surname":"aaa",         
         "obs":"eee"
      }
   }
]

let b = data.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  const { user } = rec
  return { ...acc, ...user}
}, {} )

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this after map over datas this is not a logic but.....

```
const x = data.map(obj => obj.user);

function flatObj(arr) {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(y => {
    for(const key in y) {
      res[key] = y[key];
    }
  })
  return res;
}

const resault = flatObj(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this array of objects. We can make it unique with reduce.

```
function unique(arr, key) {
    return arr.reduce((a, d) => {
        if (!a.find(ae => ae[key] === d[key]))
            a.push(d)
        return a;
    }, [])
}

let users = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'name1',
        age: 10
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name2'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'name2'
    }
];

users = unique(users, 'id')
```